# Powershell search at column

Tags: regex, powershell, match

I am searching through with following Powershell script. My script is searching through the entire line. (`and` & `or` condition are all fine)

```
Get-Content $file.fullName | ? {
  $_ -match $control -and $_ -notmatch '^\*' -and
    ($_ -match 'Call' -or $_ -match '=V' -or $_ -match '=S')
}
```

However what I really want is to search on till specific column.

To be more specific.
a) search `CALL` at column 10 to 13 only (In my current script, I am searching `Call` in whole line) 
b) $control,`=V`, `=S`   should only be searched in from starting at column 16 till I do not find a Blank character. (Currently I am searching $control, `=V`, `=S`  in whole line)

example Input:

```
CALL  $control,abcd,i,2 XXXXXXX XXXX YYYYY
```

My current script here i want to search $control, `=v`, `=s` in columns 16 through till i do not find a blank (i.e. till value `2`). I do not want to find $control, `=V`, `=S` in `XXXXXXX XXXX YYYYY`

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think the question is far to be clear, or is just my poor english?

Comment: Input is ->   CALL  $control,xghf,1 . I want to pick up only the lines in which CALL is found at column 10 from begin. also other parameters in search i.e. $control, =V, =S  in my original script should be searched in starting from column 16 till I find a blank. In above example, first blank is found after 'xghf,1'.

Comment: Must be my poor English as well then. Do you mean *character* when you say *column*, i.e. you want to check if the characters 10-13 form the (sub)string "CALL"?

Comment: Sorry. here's my one more try to put question. search 'CALL' only if it is 10th, 11th, 12th, 13th character from start of line in Notepad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
Get-Content $file.fullName | ? {
  $_.SubString(9,4) -eq 'CALL' -or $_ -match '^.{15}[^ ]*($control|=V|=S)'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Though this does not seem to work for me unless I am doing it wrong. $_ -match '^.{16}[^ ]*($control|=V|=S). What I want is Strings $Control or  =V  or =S   is searched through in 'position 16 from start'  to 'position till blank is found'

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. {16} should have been {15}. Apologies.

Comment: My mistake, actually. Fixed in the answer.